# Matched leaf route at location "/profile/1" does not have an element. React Router V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a component

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import colors from "../../utils/styles/colors";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../utils/contexte";



function Profile() {
   const { id: queryId } = useParams();
   const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/freelance?id=${queryId}`)
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((jsonResponse) => {
            setProfileData(jsonResponse?.freelaneData);
         });
   }, [queryId]);

   const { picture, name, location, tjm, job, skills, available, id } =
      profileData;
```

I am using this route in my index.js:

```
<Route path="/profile/:id" render={(props) => <Profile {...props} />}
```

But, the warning I am getting is:

index.tsx:25 Matched leaf route at location "/profile/1" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Comment: replace render with element give  try...   <Route path="/profile/:id" element={<Profile  />} />

Comment: This is what I did, the result is the same: This is what is displayed :
But, the warning I am getting is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'picture' of 'profileData' as it is undefined.

Comment: what is the profileData there ?

Comment: /*function Profile() {
   const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/freelance?id=${queryId}`)
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((jsonResponse) => {
            setProfileData(jsonResponse?.freelaneData);
         });
   }, [queryId]);*/

   /*const { picture, name, location, tjm, job, skills, available, id } =
      profileData;*/

Comment: Whats the outcode from profileData

Comment: Here is the output code of ProfileData
const { picture, name, location, tjm, job, skills, available, id } =
      profileData;

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path="/profile/:id" render={(props) => <Profile {...props} />}
```

use this instead of

```
<Route path="/profile/:id" element={<Profile props = {props} />} />
```